# marker object with list of locations

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is an object called `cleaned_trips` which is a list of trips and its a dict which has keys like `trip_distance`, `pickup_latitude`, `pickup_longitude`. Now from this list only get the keys `pickup_latitude` and `pickup_longitude` and return the marker object with the location in format `[pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude]`. This is what I tried but same location is appended all times.

```
cleaned_trips = [{'trip_distance': 18.38,
                  'pickup_latitude': 40.64499,
                  'pickup_longitude': -73.78115},
                 {'trip_distance': 1.3,
                  'pickup_latitude': 40.766931,
                  'pickup_longitude': -73.982098},
                 {'trip_distance': 4.5,
                  'pickup_latitude': 40.77773,
                  'pickup_longitude': -73.951902},
                 {'trip_distance': 2.4,
                  'pickup_latitude': 40.795678,
                  'pickup_longitude': -73.971049}]


def location(trip):
    latlng = [trip['pickup_latitude'], trip['pickup_longitude']]
    return latlng


def markers_from_trips(trips):
    new_list = []
    marker = {}
    for trip in trips:

        for key in trip:
            marker['location'] = location(trip)
            new_list.append(marker)
    return new_list


trip_markers = markers_from_trips(cleaned_trips)
print(trip_markers)  
print(len(trip_markers))
```

The output of `marker.location` should be something like this

```
# [[40.64499, -73.78115],
#  [40.766931, -73.982098],
#  [40.77773, -73.951902],
#  [40.795678, -73.971049]]
```

Here is the demo https://repl.it/repls/GroundedVariableSort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension would be perfect here:

```
>>> [[trip["pickup_latitude"], trip["pickup_longitude"]] for trip in cleaned_trips]
[[40.64499, -73.78115], [40.766931, -73.982098], [40.77773, -73.951902], [40.795678, -73.971049]]
```

You're seeing the same location appended 12 times because you only create `marker` once (on the line reading `marker = {}`) and then append it multiple times in a loop. To have a new dictionary appended to the list each time, make sure you create a fresh one on each loop:

```
def markers_from_trips(trips):
    new_list = []
    for trip in trips:
        marker = {"location": [trip["pickup_latitude"], trip["pickup_longitude"]]}
        new_list.append(marker)
    return new_list
```

or, use the list comprehension again:

```
>>> [{"location": [trip["pickup_latitude"], trip["pickup_longitude"]]} for trip in cleaned_trips]
[{'location': [40.64499, -73.78115]}, {'location': [40.766931, -73.982098]}, {'location': [40.77773, -73.951902]}, {'location': [40.795678, -73.971049]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just want to clarify "To have a new dictionary appended to the list each time, make sure you create a fresh one on each loop:". This means I should have `marker = {}` after the `for trip in trips:` statement?

Comment: Right, you can name the "marker" object and then append in two separate steps if you feel that's more clear. Updated my answer above to show that.

Comment: The thing is I have used nested loops so I could not figure out where to initialize empty marker dict. I was having problem in understanding the appending part in loops.